# How to decorate a tikz rectangle with a box on north center part?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a rectangle like the image in which I could add an image with `\includegraphics`. I have the following rectangle code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [xshift=3mm,line width=7pt,rounded corners=7pt, draw=black]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (15mm,-15mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-15mm,15mm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Use `tcolorbox` it has all of this and many more. This must be a duplicate but I can't find it.

Comment: I know with tcolorbox has the option, but I don't want to use it, that's why ask this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the question

try this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,,line width=5pt,rounded corners=5pt,](cadre){\includegraphics[width=10cm]{linux-penguin}};
        \draw [xshift=3mm,line width=5pt,rounded corners=5pt, draw=black,fill=white]
        ($ (cadre.north) + (15mm,-5mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (cadre.north) + (-15mm,5mm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with your source and comments

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                


\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [xshift=3mm,line width=7pt,rounded corners=7pt, draw=black]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (15mm,-15mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-15mm,15mm) $);
        \node at ($ (current page.north) + (0,-15mm) $) [draw,line width=5pt,rounded corners=5pt,]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{linux-penguin}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but the image was supposed to be inside the blue rectangle